# Как прописать функцию добавления записей в текстовый файл для ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Вот таким способом я читаю из файла:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Bks books = new Bks ();
    String line = null;
    ArrayList <Bk> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                 new FileInputStream("Lib.txt"), "Cp1251"));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] items = line.split(",");
            list.add(new Bk(items[0], items[1], Integer.parseInt(items[2])));
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

books.setArr(list);
```

А как мне сделать функцию записи в файл?

Answer (score 1):

Во первых вам нужно сделать метод который будет возвращать объект BK в виде строки, это может быть toString() метод класса BK или какой-то другой метод. Далее

```
public void toFile(List<Bk> list)
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("file.txt");    
    for (Bk bk : list) {
        pw.println(bk.toString());
    }
    pw.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void writeToFile(List list) throws IOException {
    Path file = Paths.get("file.txt");
    Files.write(file, list, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}
```

Comment: Ругается на Files.write(file, list, Charset.forName("UTF-8")); При чем именно на write

Comment: Нужно добавить 2 переменных типа String и 1 типа int.